# Next/Image on Next.js Not Showing

Tags: next.js, next-images

I am using next.js 11.1.0 , my images are not showing saying (image below). I tried upgrading to next.js 12 but the problem still persist. I also tried using img tag and it works fine, just  next/image not working. It seems not to work on live site production. My images are stored locally. Anyone encountered this?

[image]

```
                    <Image
                     src="images/Uploads/Activities/StoryTelling/3_2022-05-07203A383A38.jpeg"
                      width={500}
                      height={500}
                    />
```

Comment: A snippet of your code would help understand your problem. Could you also clarify if you are trying to display a local or external image?

Comment: Also try opening the page using dev server and see if you get any hints in server or browser console. You might need additional configuration inside `next.config.js`.

Comment: do you have `images/sample.jpg` in your public folder?

Comment: It works fine on dev server. I only encounter this on live server . I am using ubuntu server

Comment: You might wanna look into your configuration for static assets. In dev server they're always served locally but in a production build it might look for them on CDN or other.

Comment: Also, the comment about dev server was meant to make you find hints in console, not see if it works or not :)

Answer (score 6):

As Webber's second comment hints, [the documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving) states that all static files, like images, must be served from the `public` directory.

Another mention exists in [this tutorial](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/assets-metadata-css/assets) from Next.js.

While you are likely not still trying to figure this out, others could benefit from this clarity.

You can place your image in an `images` directory inside the public directory, and the path required would simply be `/images/sample.jpg`.

Answer (score 3):

If everything works fine on local but not in production it might be an image loader issue. I invite you to take a look at the documentation as you may need a custom function to resolve URLs.

[Image loader](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#loader)

[Built-in loader](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#built-in-loaders)

I had the same issue when deploying on GCP but everything worked on Vercel.

Answer (score 3):

You have to write src={/photoname.format} when it's Next Image, instead of the whole path.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This should be the correct answer. By default you don't have to explicitly mention `/public` directory in `src` props of `Image` component, instead you just add furthermore directory of your static file like `/images/rose.svg`, so `Next.js` will assume it to `/public/images/rose.svg`

Answer (score 2):

import img from './images/Uploads/Activities/StoryTelling/3_2022-05-07203A383A38.jpeg'

```js
<Image
  src={img}
  width={500}
  height={500}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines of code in the next.config.js file of your project folder

```js
module.exports = nextConfig

module.exports = {
  images: {
    
    formats:['image/webp']
  },
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).